# Adding onclick event while creating a tag

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a span tag dynamically and wanted to add onclick event to it.

```
$('<span>', {

    'onclick': //call some  method -> $.hello('dsfds',90),
    'class' : 'rightArrow'
}).appendTo($(elm).find('div').eq(2));
```

How can i bind onclick in above code?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('<sapn class="rightArrow"> Click of you dare</span>').click(function() {
    alert('clicked!');
}).appendTo($(elm).find('div').eq(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<span>').bind('click', function() {
  //call some  method -> $.hello('dsfds',90)
})
.addClass('rightArrow')
.appendTo($(elm).find('div').eq(2));
```